# How to compile multiple unrelated .cpp files using one g++ command

Tags: c++, compilation, g++

I am checking some assignments and they have multiple `.cpp` files each with its own main function.
And have different file names.

I want one or a series of g++ commands that I can execute, which will give me a separate executable of each file.

How do I do that?

Comment: what about using the `&&` concatenation? Or let cmake handle it..

Comment: create a makefile, possibly using automake

Comment: @MarcoA. I cant use `&&` as I dont know the file names, there is no fixed format or pattern. The file names are different for each person. Can you tell more about cmake?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are compiling using g++, I assume you have access to a shell:

```
for f in *.cpp; do g++ "$f" -o "`basename "$f"`"; done
```